# Changing localStorage data to html list tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a todo App which stores data received from input tag in an array and stores in localstorage. 
I want the data to be displayed each as a list when ever I open a new tab. I keep getting something else.

```html
<input type="text" class="input" id="input1"> 
<span class="add" id="add">Add task</span>
```

```js
var nextTask = [];
$('.add').click(function() {
  var acceptInput = $('.input').val();
  nextTask.push(acceptInput);
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(nextTask));
});

$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var a = localStorage.key(i);
    var b = localStorage.getItem(a);
    $('ul').each(function() {
      $(this).append('<li>' + JSON.parse(b) + '</li>'); // Change output from localStorage to list tag
    })
  }
});
```

My output is of this nature

```
hello, good morning, create new task, install update
```

Instead of this

```
Hello
Good morning 
Create new task
Install update
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a great code snippets tool in SO that you can use to demonstrate your code.

Comment: You are getting only one item from the localStorage eventhough thats an array, you are not looping through a parsed items but adding it as a whole

Comment: @MikePoole while thats true, the Snippet editor is counter-productive in examples using session or local storage as access to them is blocked in the snippet.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point. I suppose I was just encouraging them to display their code in its constituent files which I see you have done for them by marking it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to avoid iteration of keys in you local store when initalising your list tag, and instead, iterate the array data (if any) on the `"tasks"` key that you're storing task data against in `localStorage`.

In your case, you could update your code's "load" function so that previously persisted task data is retrieved as any array from `localStorage` via the `"tasks"` key like this:

```
/*
Fetch an array of tasks in JSON from the "tasks" key (or an empty JSON
array if nothing stored under that key) and parse the corresponding
array object
*/
const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]");
```

That would then give you an array (empty or populated with task data) which can then be iterated to populate the `ul` with inital data like this:

```
tasks.forEach(function(task) {
  /* 
  For each task in loaded task list, append an item to the ul element
  */
  $('ul').append($('<li>').text(task));
});
```

A complete solution based on this approach would be:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  const acceptInput = $('.input').val();
  
  /* Load current tasks or init to empty array if none in localStorage */
  const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]");
  
  tasks.push(acceptInput);
  
  /* Persist updated tasks list to localStoarge */
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
});


$(function() { 

  /* Load current tasks or init to empty array if none in localStorage */
  const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]");
  
  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    /* For each task in loaded task list, append an item to the ul element */
    $('ul').append($('<li>').text(task));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" id="input1"> <span class="add" id="add">Add task</span>
<ul></ul>
```

Note that the localstorage API does not work in the stackoverflows code snippet feautre, so you'll want to run this code on your own server. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 b=JSON.parse(b)
    for(let i=0;i<(b).length;i++)
     $('ul').append('<li>'  + b[i] +  '</li>');
```

As b is an array you have to iterate through all the elements and append them one by one